# International Phone Number Cleansing/ Handling/ Formatting

Tags: administration, appexchange, leads, data, website-integration

*I am in the United States, but this is a truly global concern - formatting phone numbers.*

**Situation:**  We accept "Leads" from all over the world.  We have been concentrating on North America in recent years, but have always catered to the planet as a whole.  We would like to assemble proper phone numbers as close to 100% of the time as possible.

**Factors:**   Our sales team believes currently in not having any blockages within reason to accepting their submission on our website.   Currently that means that on the vast majority of our pages, we simply ask for Phone Number (and use an IP Service) to find out what country their ISP is in to assume where they are on the planet), so we have a fairly accurate Country reference.

**Desire:**   Something in Salesforce that takes phone numbers in their myriad formats, including people putting random extra characters (the word "Home" after their number, an extension after the number, hyphens and spaces, periods, etc) and clean them to a real phone number, with their International Phone Code which we'd store in two separate fields (let's say "Clean Phone" and "Clean Phone Int Code").

I have looked around both AppExchange and Google, and I've requested some help from our current Dialer company - nothing usable has surfaced.

I know, and some here understand, we need to start asking for at least Country (perhaps crosscheck it against the IP-Country) so that we could assume that country's International Code by what they chose.   That is not foolproof either - they could still put their Int-Code in the phone field (yes, I know we could check, but let's assume they get it in somehow).

I'm doing the research for three different areas of the company - Development (which is currently influx employee-wise), Administration/Architecture (me) and Marketing (the webpages, their design, etc).   I'm a bit overwhelmed and I'm hopeful someone has resources on the web, or wherever, they could share.

My vision at the moment:    Accept anything they can throw at us (which keeps the pages from "deterring people" from filling them out as Sales is fearful of) and CLEAN that data within SF.  Raw data in one field (possibly auto-copy raw data from Phone to Phone_RAW_ORIGINAL__c?... then process from that field back to Phone).    I'd truly like to put International Code in a separate field though.

*Any guidance on people who have experience dealing with this insanity would be greatly appreciated.*   A solution may ultimately require reprogramming some members of the company to accept that we NEED to ask for more than "Phone".  But ultimately we desire to clean-and-fix it in SF.

Thanks.!

Comment: I no longer work with the company in question, but my solution ended up a placeholder involving Excel-massaging "daily" which did the trick 99.8% thoroughly, and kept very good record of raw untouched versus processed phone numbers and more.  Developers were to eventually turn my routines in VBA and Excel formulas into Apex, which I believe never happened after I left.  This question is now CLOSED (which I do not agree with) so I'm not going to worry about it further until I'm again asked to revisit this -- then I'll beg my former employer for my work product to start from  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Couple of thoughts...I think you are right - capture the raw input, and process from there. You can use a simple utility like the one below to clean the phone numbers of anything except digits. In the code below, I know US numbers are ten digits, so I only clean/re-format a number when they are ten digits. But I am thinking that you could build a lookup table of all international prefixs for countries, and then look for that at the start of the 'cleaned' number for that prefix, and then have a code library that knows how to format each country. If the number does not start with a prefix, it could also add it to make it easier for Sales folks to call them...so if someone says I am from the UK, but there is no +44 at the start, you could add it in...?

```
public static String formatphonenumber(String cphone) {
String fphone = cphone.replaceAll('\\D','');

if (fphone.length() == 10) {
fphone = formatphonenum(fphone);
return fphone;
}
else {
return cphone;
}

}

static String formatphonenum (String s) {
s = '(' + s.substring(0, 3) + ') ' + s.substring(3, 6) + '-' + s.substring(6);
return s;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, my first thought was/is to produce the stripped phone number and go from there... but there is more logic than that.  :-/   If they put "386-234-3456 Home", or NO AREA CODE, or "44-23-34-43-11 ext 234", etc etc, etc.   THAT's the fun part  (rofl)   But yes, I agree with what you general say.  We are probably going to have to release this in Waves.  Probably export all current data to look for certain patterns (like the post-phone number comments) to program around them.   Yaaaaay.   ;-)